# Divisors are cycles for (singular) homology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm sure I am missing something quite simple, but why are divisors on an algebraic variety actually homological cycles? I can see them as chains, but in order to take homology (as one always does), or to integrate along them, I would like to see them as singular cycles ($\partial D=0$). (Not just algebraic cycles, of course, which they are by definition.)

Perhaps I am just a bit confused about definitions. Thank you in advance for any clarifying suggestion.

Comment: By algebraic variety you probably mean "complete algebraic variety over ${\mathbb C}$". Otherwise, you have to do more work defining the "correct" homology theory. Compare https://ac.els-cdn.com/0040938362900940/1-s2.0-0040938362900940-main.pdf?_tid=076f9e3b-d8da-4b2c-ba19-bbfc704ab713&acdnat=1520370562_aa4388c74bc35eb49ee84371f59ba587

Comment: Yes, a complete algebraic variety over $\mathbb C$ is the context, thank you for pointing out.